# How can i run a python program without executing from terminal or any editor

Tags: python, execution

I want to run the program just like a windows program. I don't want to run it from any editor. I like to run it as any normal window. How can i do that?

Comment: Which is the OS?

Answer (score 1):

If by a normal windows program, you mean and exe file, you can create it using pyintaller library:

Make sure to install pyinstaller:

```
pip install pyinstaller
```

Create your exe file with the next command:

```
pyinstaller pythonfile.py
```

Upon this, a dist folder must be created, it will contain an exe file, you simply run it by double-clicking on it.

For more information, refer to: https://www.pyinstaller.org/

If you want to create a gui app, then you can use tkinter, or eel library.